# Why AlertifyJS confirm is not working with Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8, alertifyjs

I have setup AlertJS properly with my Angular App and it is working good for my success,error, and alert. However, the way I setup the confirm method is not working properly.

Here is the implementation for my AlertJS Service

```
confirm(title: string, message: string, okCallback: () => any, cancelCallback: () => any) {
    alertify.confirm(title, message, (e: any) => {
      if (e.button.text === 'OK') {
        okCallback();
      } else {
        cancelCallback();
      }
    });
  }

  success(message: string) {
    alertify.success(message);
  }

  error(message: string) {
    alertify.error(message);
  }

  warning(message: string) {
    alertify.warning(message);
  }

  message(message: string) {
    alertify.message(message);
  }

  alert(title: string, message: string, movable: boolean) {
    alertify.alert(title, message).set('movable', movable);
  }
```

in my component, I am calling the confirm method for the AlertifyJS as the following:

```
this.alertify.confirm('Success!',
                      'Secret questions/answers have been saved!, would you like to setup a new password?',
                      () => {
                              this.isActive = false;
                              this.isCreateNewPassword = true;
                            },
                      () => {
                              this.router.navigate(['/registrations']);
                            });
```

It is not populating the title correctly. Instead, it is keeping it as default and putting the word 'Success' as my message.

When I remove the title as a parameter from both the implementation and the call then the confirm works as expected!

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation for the confirm method should be like this

```
confirm(title: string, message: string, okCallback: () => any, cancelCallback: () => any) {
    alertify.confirm(title, message, () => { okCallback(); }
                , () => { cancelCallback(); });
  }
```